# Datatables conflicting with jquery and modal

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables in our bootstrap app. We have multiple links with data attributes set against them. When the modal is toggled then the data is extracted and then appened to the modal.

The problem is that if we do a search in the datatables then it once the link is clicked the following doesnt get called. Would this be a load issue perhaps? Any idea how to fix it?

```
$('.modal-toggle').click(function(e){
    // get control
    e.preventDefault();

    // get the vars from the data attributes
    modalType = $(this).data('modal-type').toLowerCase();
    modalTitle = $(this).data('modal-title');
    modalText = $(this).data('modal-text');

    // add appropriate footer
    if(modalType == "confirm"){
        modalUrl = $(this).data('modal-confirm-url');
        modalOptions = '<a href="' + modalUrl + '" class="btn btn-primary showhouse-colour white-text"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Yes</a><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-ban-circle"></i> No</button>';
    }else if(modalType == "alert"){
        modalOptions = '<button class="btn btn-primary showhouse-colour" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-ok"></i> OK</button>';
    }else if(modalType == 'form-confirm'){
        modalOptions = '<button class="btn showhouse-colour white" data-dismiss="modal" id="confirm-form-yes"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Yes</button><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-ban-circle"></i> No</button>';
    }

    // set modal content
    $('.modal-title').html(modalTitle);
    $('.modal-text').html(modalText);
    $('.modal-footer').html(modalOptions);

    // if we have a confirm modalType
    $('#confirm-form-yes').click(function(){
        $('.confirm-form').submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

DataTables removes non-visible rows from DOM for various reasons so when you attach an event handler it works for currently visible elements only.

> **SOLUTION**

You need to use event delegation by providing selector as a second argument in [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) call, see example below where `example` is your table ID.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#example tbody').on('click', '.modal-toggle', function (e){
       // ... skipped ...
    });
});
```

From jQuery [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method documentation:

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

See "Direct and delegated events" in jQuery [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method documentation and [jQuery DataTables – Why click event handler does not work](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-why-click-event-handler-does-not-work/) for more information.

Comment: Would / should $('#dataTable_ID') be enough to catch this?

Comment: If you mean `$('#example').on('click', `, then the answer is yes as long as you don't have elements with class `modal-toggle` in header or footer.

Comment: That works. Finally is there a way to call both as some may not be in a datatable. Don't want to be repeating the code. Is there a way to call both or would creating a function be the best course?

$('.modal-toggle').click(function(e){
$('#table_list_items').on('click', '.modal-toggle', function(e))

Comment: @PierceMcGeough, you can do `$(document.body).on('click', '.modal-toggle', function(e){ });` if you have elements outside the table.